# pygame player not loading

Tags: python, pygame

the code might seem a bit long, but everything is well commented.

first off, the error that im getting is :

```
  File "C:/Users/nellissery/Desktop/david/spaceinvader/main.py", line 56, in <module>
player()
File "C:/Users/nellissery/Desktop/david/spaceinvader/main.py", line 28, in player
screen.blit(plr, plr_x, plr_y)
TypeError: invalid destination position for blit
```

that is the error. the rest of the code is:

```
   # screen and icon
scr_height = 600
scr_width = 800
icon_sprite = 'spaceship.png'
# title:
pygame.display.set_caption('Space Invaders')

# icon:
icon = pygame.image.load(icon_sprite)
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# player
plr_sprite = 'player-ship.png'
plr_x = 200
plr_y = 200
plr = pygame.image.load(plr_sprite)

def player():
    # blit means to draw
    screen.blit(plr, plr_x, plr_y)

# in pygame, x-y axis has origin at top, left corner

#  to create a screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((scr_width, scr_height))

run = True
# the game loop:
while run:

    # background colour
    screen.fill((240,248,255))
    # to go through the events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # to check if the exit button is pressed
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    # to make sure that the changes to display are visible, we need to update display:
    # to put the player on screen:
    player()
    pygame.display.update()
```

some help would be appreciated, as i've gone through the code multiple times and don't know where im going wrong. The image is a 64 * 64. it stops working for the player function. I have saved the asset correctly and it is probably loading well. i don't understand why i get the error that

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd argument of [`pygame.Surface.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) has to be a tuple with 2 components. This tuple specifies the 2 dimensional coordinate, which specifies the top left of the source surface on the destination. Alternatively the 2nd argument can be a Rect, too.

<s>`screen.blit(plr, plr_x, plr_y)`</s>

```py
screen.blit(plr, (plr_x, plr_y))
```

Comment: Ah yes it makes sense.